# Is there a pdf-reader which can find letter ä in a document?

Tags: pdf, okular

I found that Okular won't find text that has letter ä. At least I tested with the following document:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a5paper, top=2in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes{10.0pt}  % Change base font size

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\linespread{1.3}

\begin{document}
ÄÖäö
\end{document}
```

compiled with `pdflatex demo.tex`. Is there a PDF-reader for Ubuntu that can find such letters correctly, or is there some bash script that allows me to find such strings from PDF's and scrolls Okular to the location of the string in a PDF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As probably you are using KDE, I would suggest `qpdfview` which is build on Qt libs. (Evince require more GTK libs)

1. **qpdfview**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install qpdfview
   ```

   [image]
2. **Evince**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install evince
   ```

   [image]
3. **Acroread**

   If you can't get it in software center, Check https://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/otherversions/ . Download .deb package.

   [image]

---

**Okular** *I didn't check Okular 1st, after I tried it, it does work! So what's wrong?*

[image]

Comment: Looks strange. I tried Okular today with the same file and now it finds the letter ä correctly. But it won't find the combination ÄÖ although it finds Öä and äö.

Comment: @JaakkoSeppälä, weird, `ÄÖ` works for me. Are you using deferent keyboard layouts or input systems?

Comment: I'm using Finnish keyboard layout.